# Need to mount EFS to AWS Lambda at runtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mount

I need to mount an EFS file system to AWS Lambda during runtime. The Lambda function is supposed to write some files to one of several EFS directories depending on some input / configuration. However, I don't see any option to mount multiple EFS in the AWS console statically or any API to mount it dynamically through the Lambda code.

I searched for a way to mount all 10 file systems statically to the Lambda in the configuration, but no luck there.

Comment: Probably its not possible.

Comment: Hey Marcin, probably you're right.. However, do you see any alternative way to do this? 
say generate a Lambda IAC from another Lambda and then trigger that one .. 
I am in a pickle here :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `UpdateFunctionConfiguration` [[1]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/update_function_configuration.html) in order to specify the access point and the mount path for your Lambda:

```py
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    lambda_client = boto3.client('lambda')
    function_name = 'yourFunctionName'
    local_mount_path = '/mnt/your-efs-mount-path'
    efs_access_point_arn = 'arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:REGION:ACCOUNT:access-point/your-access-point'

    out = lambda_client.update_function_configuration(
        FunctionName=function_name,
        FileSystemConfigs=[
            {
                'Arn': efs_access_point_arn,
                'LocalMountPath': local_mount_path
            }
        ]
    )

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(out["FileSystemConfigs"])
    }
```

After running the above you should see something like this in the output:

```
Response
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "[{\"Arn\": \"arn:aws:elasticfilesystem:REGION:ACCOUNT:access-point/your-access-point\", \"LocalMountPath\": \"/mnt/your-efs-mount-path\"}]"
}
```

The catch is in the documentation [[1]](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/update_function_configuration.html):

> When you update a function, Lambda provisions an instance of the function and its supporting resources.

That means this current execution won't get the mount you wish, and you would need to either restart this Lambda (new instance will have new EFS mount attached), or call `Invoke` API on this Lambda and wait for response. For your use case, you can keep repeating this process until whatever you want to have accomplished is done.

---

References: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda/client/update_function_configuration.html